# Check if post input exists in mongo database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the following node js to store values in a database...

```
//connect to database
db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function() {

    router.post('/register', function(request, response) {
        //create schema
        var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
            email    : String,
            password : String,
            display  : String   
        });

        var User = mongoose.model('User', Schema);
        //add POST values to schema
        new User({
            email: request.body.rEmail,
            password: request.body.rPwd,
            display: request.body.rDName
        //store in database
        }).save(function(err, doc) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        else 
            console.log('save user successfully...');
        });
    });
 });
```

In this file, I want to include another POST method so that I can check whether an input value exists in my database.

I have another form that looks like this in jade...

```
form(class="inputs", action="/login", method="post")
  input(type="text", name="email",class="form-control", id="emailLogin", placeholder="Queen's Email")
  input(type="submit",name = "homePage" class ="loginButton" value="Log In" id="loginButton")
```

When `name=email` is submitted, I want to check whether the value exists within the database under `email`, which is `request.body.rEmail` above in schema `User`.

I know I would have to add another function that looks like this...

```
router.post('/login', function(request, response) {
\\no idea
```

But I have no idea what to add inside. In php this is relatively easy, but researching node often leads me to unclear solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`email: {type: String, required: '{PATH} is required.', unique: true}`

If you set up your model like this, you can state that it's unique here. Mongoose will then return an error if you try to insert a duplicate.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: That's helpful, but I'm not sure if it answer my question, maybe you can clarify it for me. The schema used above registers users and stores their info to database. Then I have another form that allows a user to login. If they already have accounts (i.e their info is already stored) then they may login.

Comment: I guess I misread it a bit. You could use something like this, and on error, if it's a duplicate, login instead of registering. `res.redirect('/login');`